# Change webdriver's port

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

i need create 2-3 webDriver  instance, but i don't change port

example

```
   final int port = 7055;
      System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.port", "" + port);
      FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile();
      fp.setPreference(FirefoxProfile.PORT_PREFERENCE, port);
      WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(fp);
```

but this doesn't work

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the port that Webdriver Firefox connects to localhost?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919769/how-to-change-the-port-that-webdriver-firefox-connects-to-localhost)

Comment: @olyv yes, of course.