# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError while creating a FirefoxDriver in java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

While trying to:

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.Proxy.extractFrom(Lorg/openqa/selenium/Capabilities;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/Proxy;
  at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.dropCapabilities(FirefoxDriver.java:313)
  at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:191)
  at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
  at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
  at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
```

This problem started right after firefox on ubuntu updated to 32.0 version, I tried to install version 28.0 but still didn't worked.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

After changing drivers version to 2.39 like **curiosu** said, a new error shows:

```
 org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on       port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
pp-system-share:{2e1445b0-2682-11e1-bfc2-0800200c9a66} visible
1409862347400   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1409862347400   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1409862347405   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1409862347405   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1409862347406   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1409862347407   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-ZA@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi
1409862347408   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-GB@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi
1409862347408   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-ar@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi
1409862348534   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1409862348581   addons.manager  DEBUG   shutdown
1409862348587   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1409862348587   addons.xpi  DEBUG   shutdown
1409862348588   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   shutdown
1409862348644   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1409862348644   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 16
1409862348645   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Notifying XPI shutdown observers
1409862348649   addons.manager  DEBUG   Async provider shutdown done

(process:3519): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed

(firefox:3519): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised

(firefox:3519): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::show-crash-dialog after class was initialised

(firefox:3519): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::display after class was initialised

(firefox:3519): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::default-icon after class was initialised
1409862349347   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm: ["XPIProvider"]
1409862349349   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/LightweightThemeManager.jsm: ["LightweightThemeManager"]
1409862349352   addons.xpi  DEBUG   startup
1409862349354   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping ubufox@ubuntu.com to /usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/ubufox@ubuntu.com
1409862349354   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping {2e1445b0-2682-11e1-bfc2-0800200c9a66} to /usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/{2e1445b0-2682-11e1-bfc2-0800200c9a66}
1409862349355   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping langpack-en-ZA@firefox.mozilla.org to /usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-ZA@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi
1409862349355   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping langpack-en-GB@firefox.mozilla.org to /usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-GB@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi
1409862349355   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} to /usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1409862349355   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping langpack-ar@firefox.mozilla.org to /usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-ar@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi
1409862349356   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: /tmp/anonymous3480147629030289426webdriver-profile/extensions/webdriver-staging
1409862349356   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping fxdriver@googlecode.com to /tmp/anonymous3480147629030289426webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com
1409862349357   addons.xpi  DEBUG   checkForChanges
1409862349363   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
1409862349367   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-ZA@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi
1409862349367   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-en-GB@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi
1409862349368   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/langpack-ar@firefox.mozilla.org.xpi
*** Blocklist::_preloadBlocklistFile: blocklist is disabled
   JavaScript error: chrome://browser/content/urlbarBindings.xml, line 677: aUrl is undefined

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:250)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:112)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:195)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:190)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:99)
```

Solution: I finally managed to resolve the problem, I changed selenium webDriver version from 2.42.2 to 2.39.0 and downgraded firefox version from 32.0 to 28.0

Answer (score 5):

Had the same Exception with the update to FireFox 32 and Selenium Firefox Webdriver 2.40.0 on Windows 7. I'll post my solution here, maybe it won't solve your problem but it could be the solution for others with the same problem who land here after searching.

Somehow the `selenium-remote-driver` does not get correctly updated, while it is present in the POM file for the `selenium-firefox-driver`. My solution was adding the remote driver to my own POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.43.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.43.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I had to restart my IDE (IntelliJ) and rebuild the project, but after that it worked.

Final config:

- FireFox 32.0.3
- Selenium FireFox driver 2.43.1
- Selenium Remote driver 2.43.1

Comment: Placing the `selenium-firefox-driver` dependency explicitly above 
`selenium-remote-driver` solved to me. My Firefox is the latest at the moment (33.1.1) and it worked with selenium both 2.43.1 and 2.44.0 (this one also latest selenium and firefox-driver version).

Comment: Hey AutomatedChaos 
It really worked , thanks for the solution. Vote +1

Answer (score 0):

You are having some Compability issue between the two. the easy way will be to find a version that is compatible with ubuntu 32.0

Comment: Firefox is the one with version 32.0, not ubuntu. Which version is the one you say it's creating the compatibility issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an **older** version of **FirefoxDriver**.

Use the older FirefoxDriver (e.g.: 2.39) with Firefox 32.

Comment: Already changed my question, do you have any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919769/how-to-change-the-port-that-webdriver-firefox-connects-to-localhost

Answer (score 0):

Please try older FF build.Currently i also observe such kind of issue FF build no 32 with latest selenium but after reverting changes to older build my issue get resolved successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If selenium code is being executed for the first time after jars are imported

Right click on project->Build Path->Configure Build Path...->Order and Export->get selenium java,server-standalone jars just below JRE Library->OK

Re-execute the code, it will work.